# Teradata Error 42000

Tags: odbc, teradata

I am getting following error while executing sql command through ODBC.

Details: "ODBC: ERROR [42000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Syntax error, expected something like an 'UDFCALLNAME' keyword between '.' and the 'SUM' keyword. "

The code i am running is following.

`SELECT t1.BALANCE_DATE, t1.SUM(LCY_BALANCE) AS TOTAL_DEP, t2.SUM(LCY_BALANCE) AS TOTAL_CASH
FROM
(SELECT LCY_BALANCE, BALANCE_DATE FROM MY_BALANCE_TABLE
WHERE LINE_NUMBER BETWEEN '2300' AND '3311' AND BALANCE_DATE BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND 2016-06-30' AND BRANCH_CODE = '5520'
GROUP BY BALANCE_DATE) t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT LCY_BALANCE, BALANCE_DATE FROM MY_BALANCE_TABLE
WHERE LINE_NUMBER IN ('0040','0050','0060','0105','0110','0115') AND BALANCE_DATE BETWEEN '2015-07-01' AND 2016-06-30' AND BRANCH_CODE = '5520'
GROUP BY BALANCE_DATE) t2
ON
t1.BALANCE_DATE = t2.BALANCE_DATE`

What could be the error, please guide.

Regards

KAM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't qualify the `SUM`:

```
SELECT t1.BALANCE_DATE,
     SUM(t1.LCY_BALANCE) AS TOTAL_DEP, 
     SUM(t2.LCY_BALANCE) AS TOTAL_CASH
FROM
```